# A new tag with <tag> gets added in my pom after doing a release on git server

Tags: java, git, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven-based java project which I released on Bitbucket git server recently using `mvn:release perform` command and it was successful. However, after the release was done my pom.xml got modified automatically with the code snippet `<tag>HEAD</tag>` in the  tag which kind of surprised me because when doing a release on subversion in my past projects I never had seen this occurring ever.

```xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/jobmon.git</connection>
    <url>https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/jobmon</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://nitalchandel@bitbucket.org/nitalchandel/jobmon.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this a new feature of maven or git or bitbucket?
2. Could this be happening because of my NetBeans editor? (I am doing releases from Windows command prompt)
3. Could this be happening because of maven-release-plugin my pom which I have mentioned below?
4. Is this a good or bad thing?

**pom.xml**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>${project.name}-v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this a new feature of maven or git or bitbucket?

This is a feature of the `maven-release-plugin`, since [version 2.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-723). When the goal `release:prepare` is invoked, the `<tag>` element is used to store the URL of the SCM storing the tag. For example, for SVN, when the SCM used is 
`svn://project/trunk`, the `<tag>` element will be
replaced by `svn://project/tags/project-1.0`. With Git, there is no such information (there is no URL storing the tag per se) so the `<tag>` element gets set to `HEAD`.

> 2. Could this be happening because of my NetBeans editor? (I am doing releases from Windows command prompt)

Definitely not, this is purely related to the `maven-release-plugin`.

> 3. Could this be happening because of maven-release-plugin my pom which I have mentioned below?

No, [`<tagNameFormat>`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat) tells the `maven-release-plugin` the name to choose when creating the tag. By default, the name used is `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}` but you can override it to what you want.

> 4. Is this a good or bad thing?

This is an informational element. The intent is to show that this POM is the result of a release. AFAIK, it will always be added by the `maven-release-plugin` and there is no reason to remove it.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed response :)